# How to change the max_brightness value in LED drivers

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver, led

How can I change the `max_brightness` value in the LED subsystem sysfs parameter. It always shows 255. Can it be changed to higher number say 65536  from within the driver code so that whenever I do `cat brightness` I get the max value I set in the code? 
Does the 0-255 value needs to be mapped to the actual brightness values of the led in the driver code?

Example: if the max brightness value of the LED is AAAA that means value x can be mapped as `(x * 65536/255)`

Comment: It's unsigned long which is limited by certain driver. One might use 0-255, other 0-15, or 0-65535.

Comment: Are you asking as a user or a driver developer?

Comment: as a driver developer !

Comment: slightly updated the question